# Mysql access main table inside right joined subquery

Tags: sql, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

```
SELECT id,region FROM ads     
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT * FROM ads a2 WHERE a2.region=ads.region LIMIT 4) AS regions    
ON regions.id=ads.id
```

Says "unknown column ads.region". How to access main table column region?

I need to fetch 4 rows for each region

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
    SELECT a.id,
           a.region 
      FROM ads a    
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT t.*,
                   CASE 
                      WHEN @region = t.region THEN @rownum := @rownum + 1
                      ELSE @rownum := 1
                   END as rank,
                   @region := t.region
              FROM ADS t
              JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0, @region := 1) r
          ORDER BY t.region) b ON b.id = a.id
                              AND b.region = a.region
                              AND b.rank <= 4
```

Comment: Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: @Beck: I updated it to use `a`, but you've not given any indication which you want.  Change the reference to `b` if necessary.