# Mysql alternative for LIMIT inside subquery in mysql 5.1.49

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

```
SELECT student_id FROM `students` AS s1
WHERE student_id IN 
  (SELECT s2.student_id FROM `students` AS s2
     WHERE s1.year_of_birth = s2.year_of_birth
     LIMIT 10)
```

Can't process this query on my server. It drops errors, that says that this version of mysql doesn't support limit inside subqueries etc(ERROR 1235).

Is there any solution for my version of mysql 5.1.49?

```
SELECT
    id,
    region
FROM (
    SELECT
        region,
        id,
        @rn := CASE WHEN @prev_region = region
                    THEN @rn + 1
                    ELSE 1
               END AS rn,
        @prev_region := region
    FROM (SELECT @prev_region := NULL) vars, ads T1
    ORDER BY region, id DESC
) T2
WHERE rn <= 4
ORDER BY region, id
```

Thanks to **Mark Byers**

Comment: Here is a workaround, can't say how well it'll work but try it out: http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/211239

Comment: Can you explain what it is that you are trying to do, in words? Or with a worked example with example input and expected output.

Comment: Should be the same technique as the other question you just asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537987/mysql-access-main-table-inside-right-joined-subquery

Comment: it should pick 10 rows for each birth date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want any ten students with each birthdate. This is a greatest-n-per-group query and you can [search Stack Overflow](http://www.google.com/search?q=greatest-n-per-group+mysql+site%3Astackoverflow.com) to see how this can be done in MySQL.

It would be easy if MySQL supported the ROW_NUMBER function, but since it does not you can emulate it using variables. For example to get 3 students for each birth date you could do it like this:

```
SELECT
    student_id,
    year_of_birth
FROM (
    SELECT
        year_of_birth,
        student_id,
        @rn := CASE WHEN @prev_year_of_birth = year_of_birth
                    THEN @rn + 1
                    ELSE 1
               END AS rn,
        @prev_year_of_birth := year_of_birth
    FROM (SELECT @prev_year_of_birth := NULL) vars, students T1
    ORDER BY year_of_birth, student_id DESC
) T2
WHERE rn <= 3
ORDER BY year_of_birth, student_id
```

Result:

```
1, 1990
2, 1990
5, 1990
4, 1991
7, 1991
8, 1991
6, 1992
```

Test data:

```
CREATE TABLE students (student_id INT NOT NULL, year_of_birth INT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO students (student_id, year_of_birth) VALUES
(1, 1990),
(2, 1990),
(3, 1991),
(4, 1991),
(5, 1990),
(6, 1992),
(7, 1991),
(8, 1991);
```

Comment: erm actually it should pick 10 rows for each birth date

Comment: well actually i need to pick 4 rows for each "whatever"

Comment: You just have to change the number from 3 to 10 (or 4) on line `WHERE rn <= 3`.

Comment: thanks mate! at last some guru answered my call of help :)
it's working.
btw can you please suggest me some book about such advanced mysql queries? thanks again ;)