# SELECT sql statement that retrieves one row from a table and many related rows from other table

Tags: php, mysql

I working in a poll script, i have two tables {hs_questions_q}{hs_answers_ans} the first one stored the question and the second stored its answers

i used this sql statement to retrieve the data

```
SELECT * FROM hs_questions_q INNER JOIN hs_answers_ans ON id_q=idq_ans WHERE active_q ='1' and home_q ='1' ORDER BY id_q DESC limit 1
```

what i was wonder and i can't deal with in my php code is how that this query returned the last row only from the the question table and answers table, but i need to retrieve the last row from the question table and all rows related to it from the answers table

Comment: select * form hs_answer_ans where idq_ans in (select id_q from hs_questions_q active_q ='1' and home_q ='1' ORDER BY id_q DESC limit 1)

Comment: @RajatSinghal Thanks for your reply, i think it get more closer from the solution, but it seems to be there is an error in the statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return 1 row per question in the table not as the num rows of answers:

I assume the structure:

`hs_questions_q (id,desc)`

`hs_answers_ans(id,desc)`

```
SELECT question.desc, group_concat(hs_answers_ans.desc SEPARATOR '#')
FROM (select * 
          from hs_questions_q 
          where active_q ='1' and home_q ='1' ORDER BY id_q DESC limit 1) question
INNER JOIN hs_answers_ans ON id_q=idq_ans
group by question.id

result:
question1 | Answer1#Answer2#Answer3
```

Later, you can split it by '#' after retrieving the result on the php side.

You might get truncated answers if it exceeds the allowed packet size. You can solve it by,

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 6000(any threshold);
```

Comment: great, i will try this but can you explain more what to put instead of separator #, and what about (question) before the inner join statement, do you mean (hs_question_q)

Comment: yes it means table 'hs_question_q' only. the 'question' has been used as alias for table 'hs_question_q'. Good convention is to write with 'AS' clause i.e For eg: from () as question. i latest version if mysql  though not mention it will accept as alias but in earlier version we had to mention else will throw an error.

Comment: For separator you can decide any character. For if there is any possibilty of # to appear in answer then change to any other character u like which you think will not be used by answers or use '###'. The possibility of using 3 times is rare.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's roughly what you're looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM 
         (select * 
          from hs_questions_q 
          where active_q ='1' and home_q ='1' ORDER BY id_q DESC limit 1) question
 INNER JOIN hs_answers_ans ON id_q=idq_ans
```

I don't know whether active_q and home_q belong to question table or answers

Comment: thanks for that effort, active_q and home_q belongs to question table, in your query i understand everything you write, although the query retrieve all the data from answers table and create the question table row retrieved with every row returned from the answered table

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are trying to grab one row and join it with more than one row of different data... I don't think that will work.

I would select the question and then use the id from the question to grab all the answers separately.

Comment: great, also i would do this but i need to put the poll in the home page so how can i retrieve the answers from the answers table via the $_GET var without passing the var to the url

Comment: This would be very easy to do with ajax... I would suggest using jquery if you are not already... http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks, i will keep it up to try

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from hs_answer_ans where idq_ans in (select id_q from hs_questions_q where active_q ='1' and home_q ='1' ORDER BY id_q DESC limit 1)
```

Sorry some typo was there in comment...:)

Comment: unfortunately i get this error {This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'}

Comment: In that case you can either go for alernative from this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537999/mysql-alternative-for-limit-inside-subquery-in-mysql-5-1-49

Comment: or you can first get result of the inner query and by php take first element of it and then run main query for the one result..

Answer (score 0):

This query should give you the desired result:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `hs_questions_q` 
INNER JOIN `hs_answers_ans` ON `id_q` = `idq_ans` 
WHERE `idq_ans` = (
    SELECT MAX(`id_q`)
    FROM `hs_questions_q`
    WHERE `active_q` ='1'
    AND `home_q` ='1'
    );
```

Hope it helps!